# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000 hashfunc

Tags: c++

Im trying to execute my program and receive this error message 
Here my main

```
int numofsect=2;
unsigned char** hash_table;
hash_table = new unsigned char*[numofsect];
for (int i=0; i < numofsect; i++)
    hash_table[i] = new unsigned char[CryptoPP::SHA::DIGESTSIZE];
char** tab;
tab = new char*[numofsect];
for (int i=0; i< numofsect; i++)
    tab[i] = new char[5];
int* tabsize;
tabsize = new int[2];
tabsize[0]=5;
tabsize[1]=5;

printf("Type sections:\n");
printf("Sect1: ");
scanf("%s", tab[0]);
printf("\nSect2: ");
scanf("%s", tab[1]);
hasher(numofsect, tab, tabsize, hash_table);
printf("Your hashed tab is:\n");
printf("hash sect1: ");
printf("%s",hash_table[0]);
printf("\nhash sect2: ");
printf("%s",hash_table[1]);

delete[] hash_table;
delete[] tab;
delete[] tabsize;
```

Here my hash func:

```
void hasher (int num_of_sect, char** sect_tab, int* size_of_sect_tab, unsigned char** hash_tab )
{
  for (int i=0 ; i<=num_of_sect ; i++) { // i is the number of each secion
    byte haSha1[CryptoPP::SHA::DIGESTSIZE]; //Byte table to calculate the hash of the section i
    byte* chaine = (byte*)malloc(sizeof(byte)*size_of_sect_tab[i]); //chaine reiceive the byte stream of the section i
    for (int j=0 ; j<size_of_sect_tab[i]; j++) //j is the n-th byte of the section
        chaine[j]=sect_tab[i][j]; //copy each byte of the sect_tab in the chaine


    CryptoPP::SHA().CalculateDigest(haSha1, chaine, size_of_sect_tab[i]); //Hash the section and return it in haSha1
    for (int j=0; j<CryptoPP::SHA::DIGESTSIZE; j++) //j is the n-th byte of the hashed section
        hash_tab[i][j]=haSha1[j]; //copy each byte of the hash to the hash_table
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're dereferencing a pointer containing NULL somewhere, use a debugger ...

Comment: I think its for (int i=0 ; i<=num_of_sect ; i++) {

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing outside the bounds of your sect_tab array when i = num_of_sect in the following code:

```
 chaine[j]=sect_tab[i][j];
```

You can not have

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=num_of_sect ; i++) {
```

since you pass tab = new char*[numofsect];

Remember that arrays are indexed from 0 to size-1.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop in the hasher function should not be `<=` but just `<` like this:

```
  for (int i=0 ; i < num_of_sect ; i++)
```

That's probably the issue. Please just use a debugger and step through it and you'll soon see where the problem lies. Debuggers are our greatest friends!

Zero based indexes!